# Activity containing a Bundle

Tags: android, bundle

How to check if an Activity contains a Bundle?
Here is the code that allows me to store a value in my initial Activity

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putStringArray("contact_to_bundle", new String[]{nomStr, prenomStr, numeroStr, imageStr});
   i.putExtras(bundle);

  startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you:
Start your Activity2 like this:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putStringArray("contact_to_bundle", new String[]{nomStr, prenomStr, numeroStr, imageStr});
   i.putExtras(bundle);
   startActivity(i);
```

Then in onCreate method of your Activity2 check something like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null){
      //Your activity contains bundle.
      //Check for values in your bundle
      if (bundle.containsKey("contact_to_bundle")){
            bundle.getStringArray("contact_to_bundle");
      }
} else {
     //Your activity not contains bundle.
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @AndiM this anwers resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle.containsKey()` is the method which checks whether an activity contains any bundle or not.
Replace your code with this to check null bundle:

Activity who is **sending bundle**:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
 bundle.putStringArray("contact_to_bundle", new String[]{nomStr,
                    prenomStr, numeroStr, imageStr});
 i.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(i);
```

Activity which is **fetching bundle**:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle=getIntent().getExtras;
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("contact_to_bundle")) {
            //fetch values
            bundle.getStringArray("contact_to_bundle");

        }
    }
```